# Making two similar functions generic

Tags: generics, go, slice, generic-programming

I have two functions in Go that do almost the same. They take a slice of structs which has an 'ID' field, and re-sort it into a map indexed by that field. They then append it to a field of another struct, which is also identified by the ID.

The two functions do the same, but append to two different fields in the struct. I want to make the methods generic, but I am not sure how to do it. I would expect it could be done using a pointer, but I'm not sure how.

Function 1:

```
func addPremiereDatesToMovies(m []Movie, pd []PremiereDate) ([]Movie, error) {
    pds := make(map[int64][]PremiereDate)

    // Key-index the premiere-date array for easier lookup
    for _, value := range pd {
        pds[value.Id] = append(pds[value.Id], value)
    }

    // Append premiere dates to movies where such exist
    for key, value := range m {
        if _, ok := pds[value.Id]; !ok {  // <-- How to make this generic?
            m[key].PremiereDates = []PremiereDate{}
            continue
        }

        m[key].PremiereDates = pds[value.Id]
    }

    return m, nil
}
```

Function 2:

```
func addGenresToMovies(m []Movie, g []Genre) ([]Movie, error) {
    gs := make(map[int64][]Genre)

    // Key-index the genre array for easier lookup
    for _, value := range g {
        gs[value.Id] = append(gs[value.Id], value)
    }

    // Append genres to movies where such exist
    for key, value := range m {
        if _, ok := gs[value.Id]; !ok { // <-- How to make this generic?
            m[key].Genres = []Genre{}
            continue
        }

        m[key].Genres = gs[value.Id]
    }

    return m, nil
}
```

As it seems, they look quite similar. I am able to sort of do it, except I cannot figure out how to generically describe the "value.Id" field on line 11.

Thank you.

Comment: i think for the code you presented in your question there is little benefit of having a generic function. two separate functions are perfectly fine, readable and type safe. you can save a few lines of code by not creating empty slice for missing ids (just use nil instead).

Comment: I've tried to compose a solution but it seems your code is flowed. You are building `pds` & `gds` maps that are keyed by PremierDate and Genre `Id` but then you are looking up by movie ID: `gs[value.Id]`. Does not make any sense to me.

Also note instead of `m[key].Genres = ` you can do `value.Genres = `

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with [kostya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3477832/kostya) that having it as separate functions is perfectly fine, it might become less maintainable if you want to add 20+ items to a movie - like `cast` ,`revenues_per_country`, etc. You'd be left with 20+ functions.

The following function would compress it into one function, but you'll need to add different `case` sections for each field you want to add.

To use it, simply drop it in place of your current calls:

Usage:
`movies = addStuffToMovies(movies, genres)`

```
// addStuffToMovies adds fields to a movie where the ID matches
func addStuffToMovies(movies []Movie, stuff interface{}) []Movie {

    // Go through the movies list
    for current, movie := range movies {

        // check the type and append based on that
        switch v := stuff.(type) {

        // This is the section you'll need to duplicate for each type of field
        case []Genre:
            for _, item := range v {
                // if it matches, append it to Genres
                if item.Id == movie.Id {
                    movies[current].Genres = append(movies[current].Genres, item)
                }
            }

        // This is the section you'll need to duplicate for each type of field
        case []PremiereDate:
            for _, item := range v {
                // if it matches, append it to PremiereDates
                if item.Id == movie.Id {
                    movies[current].PremiereDates = append(movies[current].PremiereDates, item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return movies
}
```

You could probably take it a step further by adding an [interface](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types), then instead of `stuff interface{}` you'll have something like `[]FieldInterface` with calls like `GetID()`, `GetType()` instead of the different `case` sections. I think you'll still need to do type checking somewhere to actually assign it to the movie. This will probably be way to much effort when a `switch` like above will work fine.